# How to auto run Webpack-dev-server after each save?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I want to auto run and auto refresh webpack-dev-server when I used the package `AutoSave OnChange` of `Atom`  and run my application.

My `webpack-dev-server`  is :

```
devServer: {
        contentBase: './src/index.js',
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        compress: true,
        port: 3001, // port number
        historyApiFallback: true,
        quiet: true,
    }
```

I use the Reactify template, and the scriptsof my package.json is :

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --inline --progress",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
```

Comment: it can be achieved through Reat Hot Module Reload - http://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/getstarted/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a watch flag to your start script.

"start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --inline --progress --watch"

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the `--watch` flag to your start script!

Answer (score 0):

WDS will handle restarting the server when you change a bundled file, but what about when you edit the webpack config? Restarting the development server each time you make a change tends to get boring after a while. The process can be automated as discussed in GitHub by using "nodemon" monitoring tool.

To get it to work, you have to install it first through npm install nodemon --save-dev. After that, you can make it watch webpack config and restart WDS on change. Here's the script if you want to give it a go:

package.json

"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon --watch webpack.config.js --exec \"webpack-dev-server --mode development\"",
  "build": "webpack --mode production"
},
It's possible WDS will support the functionality itself in the future. If you want to make it reload itself on change, you should implement this workaround for now.

Answer (score 0):

The marked answer didn't work for me (as of 2023). Most of the flags returned an unknown error.

What worked for me is:

```
{ "start" : "webpack-dev-server --mode development --progress"}
```